# What's it called when, in a proof, we define a new variable/function in terms of two existing ones, in order to make it easier to write or follow?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question

Say, for instance, we're trying to prove a theorem involving two defined functions $f$ and $g$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Within this proof, we have to deal with the sum $f(x) + g(x)$ multiple times.

So we decide, at some point, to write:

> $$ \text{call } h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$$

to make the proof easier to write or read.

1. What do we call this operation?
2. And could we write 'let' instead of 'call'?

Comment: I would call it a "local definition". using "Call" or "Let" is purely optional in my humble opinion.

Comment: A [model-theoretic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory) aside: while as far as I know there's no name for this as a step in exposition, there is a "structural" analogue: passing from one structure to another by adding symbols for already-definable relations/functions/etc. This is called "expansion by definitions." E.g. going from [(the natural numbers with addition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) to (the natural numbers with addition and less-than) is an expansion by definitions, since in the natural numbers we have $a<b$ iff $\exists c(a+c=b)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I don't think this operation has any name. I would describe the step as "introducing" or "constructing" a new function
2. I think "let" is acceptable, but (and this opinion is purely subjective) not quite as good. "let" is usually there to instantiate universally quantified variables, that is, if the statement starts with $\forall \epsilon > 0$, we start the proof by saying "Let $\epsilon>0$" to say that we allow $\epsilon$ to be any positive number. Instead of either call or let, I would say "define" or "construct".

Comment: "Construction" might be a good name for it then. I've seen it used in a few proofs (e.g. "this is true by construction of $x$", where $x$ is a variable that was assigned a certain value beforehand)

Answer (score 1):

That proof strategy does not have a name.

"Let" is much better than "call". You want your reader to know that you are defining something, not simply renaming something they might think they should remember from earlier.

Edit: @5xum suggests "define" instead of "let". That is probably better.